# HTML: how to add image as background overlay

Tags: html, wordpress

I use WordPress with Kadence theme and I have a page called blog set as my posts page so it shows all my posts.  I want to add some  HTML code which places an image to the archive title background by adding it as a background overlay.  The reason I want to do this is because I have added some CSS code to the archive title background which adds a gradient color, and I want to blend this gradient color in with the background image.

The CSS which i added to the archive title background to give gradient color is:

```
<? php $page_for_posts = get_option( 'page_for_posts' ); ?> .entry-hero-container-inner {background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, black);}
```

This works fine but then when I add an image to the archive title background via the archive layout customise settings, the page then only shows the image and not the gradient colour.  When i then add the background-blend-mode code as additional css to blend the image and the gradient colour, it doesn't work.

So i am thinking that maybe i need to add the image to the archive title background by adding it as a background overlay but not sure how to add this html code as Kadence doesn't allow you to add any shortcode html to the archive title background.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$page_for_posts = get_option('page_for_posts');
?>
.entry-hero-container-inner {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red, black), url('your-image-url.jpg') center/cover no-repeat;
    background-blend-mode: overlay; 
}
```